# Changing page number in hyperref bookmark

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have a book that is published under CC-BY. But it contains some CC-BY-NC-ND chapters, which I want to exclude from certain versions of the book. So instead of including the chapters I include dummy chapters. But each chapter comes with a footer providing the reference to the chapter and I want the page numbers to be correct. I also want the bookmarks of the PDF to point to the right page. I managed to set up everything but the bookmark gives the page number of the ende of the chapter as page number. Is there a way to change this? In the MWE below I want the pagenumber of chap2 to appear in the bookmarks. Chapter 3 should start on page 335, which it does. In my setting I get chap2 to have the right page number but the bookmark shows the last number. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}


\chapter{Chapter 2}
\label{chap2}

This chapter goes from page~\pageref{chap2} to page~\pageref{chap2-end}.


\setcounter{page}{333}
\label{chap2-end}


\chapter{Chapter 3}


\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Added picture showing the bookmarks and numbers.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see page numbers in the bookmarks? Do you mean the output of \pageref{chap2}?

Comment: No, when you look at the pdf the viewer shows page numbers. I want it to show the page number of the beginning of the chapter. Not the page number of the (faked) end. I guess one can force this by inserting blank pages, but I want to avoid this.

Comment: I don't see this number. But as you are changing the page number on the same page as the title of chapter 2 this chapter does start on page 333 -- page numbers are fixed when the page it output.

Comment: If you want to skip the dummie pages maybe `\addtocounter{page}{-333}` is probably what you are searching for. But i'm not sure if i understand you ...

Comment: Seeing Ulrike's answer, I guess my question does not have a solution. I have to add extra pages.